# In DDD, where to place a "find or create" kind of logic?

Tags: php, laravel, domain-driven-design

> **The Requirements**

In a certain use case we get a string...

```
StringX = "some value"
```

We want to get an [Object A] whose property [Property X] matches this string.
In case no [Object A] matches that value, it needs to be created (hence the title find or create).

**The process of creating the [Object A] is more complex that merely adding an entry to a database.**

> **The Question**

If this was a matter of just finding the object I could just do:

```
$objectARepo = new ObjectARepository();
$objectA = $objectARepo->findByStringX($stringX);
```

However, maybe there are no ObjectA that matches StringX and it needs to be created.

I am struggling to decide how to handle this logic.

Should a Service do this? But Services should not be used for searching for objects, isn't it?

Would something like this make sense?

```
$objectAService = new ObjectAService(new ObjectARepository());
$objectA = $objectAService->findOrCreateByStringX($stringX);
```

Comment: you want some method like firstOrCreate or firstOrNew?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case? Silently creating an aggregate root when you don't find one is very unusual.

Comment: @MahdiYouseftabar I want to know what would be the appropriate place for such method.

Comment: @guillaume31 Added details. I don't want to silently create the objects, hence wanting to explicitly call it "findOrCreate" instead of just "find" and placing it in a repository. I don't think repositories should decide to make something if it does not exist

Comment: Oftentimes, `findOrCreate` methods are used in technical layers to avoid duplication but not exposed to the end user. Is that the case here (your additional details don't say if "we" is the user or the programmer)?

Comment: @guillaume31That is the case indeed. Nothing here is exposed to any real users

Comment: It's very hard to answer without more details about what `Object A` and `Property X` really are. I guess my advice would be to put it in an application service if it's application logic or in a domain factory if it's domain logic...

Answer (score 4):

It is not very common that business logic will require creating a new aggregate if it was not found because for creating you usually need all the properties of the aggregate. And for searching it is only few of them.

Now let's assume this need to be done. I suggest it should not be a repository function called findOrCreate() since the repository should only care about persistence and not how the objects are being created. The best place would be the service (usually it is application service) where you are calling the repository.

```
$objectA = $this->objectARepo->findByStringX($stringX);
$objectA = $objectA ?? $this->createNewObjectA($stringX);
$this->objectARepo->add($objectA);
```

The createNewObjectA() will contain the logic related to setting default values for the newly created object. If your aggregate is complicated you can use a factory.